# can't display image in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to show an image(named 1.png) in the template hashtag_details.html(both image and this files are in same directory)

[image: project tree]

hashtag_details.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Trends Result</title>
    <!--script>
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = "{{ request.path }}";
        }, 3000);
    </script-->
</head>
<body>

<img src="1.png">

</body>
</html>
```

this is how my settings.py looks. kindly check and let me know what's wrong. I don't know where to keep images and from where to access them.

```
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['Trends/templates/trends'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: i know it can be a possible duplicate for many questions but i tried all the answers nothing works..

Comment: Did you tried inspecting the image url in browser ? Whats the absolute url being generated ? Maybe there is some issue with static files settings

Comment: @Umair i inspected the urls it says `<img src="1.png">` and it means `127.0.0.1:8000/1.png` i tried appending whole path `<img src="/Trends/templates/trends/1.png">` but it doesn't work

Comment: What's your media settings ?

Comment: This maybe happening due to misconfigured media/static root/url, kindly check them

Comment: i am updating setting.py check edit @Umair

Comment: Set STATIC_ROOT also check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172400/discussion-between-nandish-patel-and-umair).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to let django serve these media files.

For example:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media')
```

Second you need to add it to your urlpatterns so django knows where to serve it.

```
urlpatterns = [
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

After you have done these two steps you can check if you did everything correct in the browser. For example: `http:localhost:8000/static/media/your_image.png`. There you will see only the image.

In principle your client code makes a Http-Get to the server. So you need to send the full url like you can see above if you want to serve it directly to the client.